# Updating Parent Record on delete of editable Sub-grid record

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a parent record (budget) that I need to have a live update on the total of the child records (budget items). Each time the a Budget Item is updated/added/removed, I need to the parent records to update the total. This needs to be done on the parent (budget) form in real time with the budget items being in an editably sub-grid.

I tried the following code

```
var gridContext = formContext.getControl("EditableSubGridName");

//Verify the subgrid is loaded, if not recursively call function again
if (gridContext != null && gridContext != undefined) {
    gridContext.addOnLoad(CalculateTotal);
}
```

The above only gets called on a Save, it is not triggered on a deletion of a sub-grid record.